# Ajax pass complex parameter syntax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using an ajax post and passing a json object as parameter to an mvc controller

I've noticed everything is ok if I call ajax this way

```
vm.updateRoom = function(ctx){
    var test = ko.toJSON(ctx);
        return $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    url: 'myUrl',
                    data: test
                }).success(function (data) {
                    //...
                }).fail(function (xhr,error,status) {
                    //...
       }); 
    }
```

but the call fails this way

```
vm.updateRoom= function(ctx){
    var test = ko.toJSON(ctx);

    if(validator1 && validator2 && validator3 && validator4){
        return $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    url: 'myurl',
                    data: { room: test }
                }).success(function (data) {
                      //...
                }).fail(function (xhr,error,status) {
                      //..
       }); 
    }
};
```

I examinated the xhr content and in the first case i a json object, in second case is a %7B%22Id%22%3A%221%22%2C%2... string.
The controller expects a complex object as parameter.

How can I manage to pass a json object with the 2nd syntax?

Comment: can u show your controller action code that you want to call?

Answer (score 0):

```
vm.updateRoom= function(ctx){
    var test = ko.toJSON({room:ctx}); //some js variable 

    if(validator1 && validator2 && validator3 && validator4){
        return $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    url: 'room/update',
                    data: test
                }).success(function (data) {
                      //...
                }).fail(function (xhr,error,status) {
                      //..
       }); 
    }
};
```

for completeness I have added a sample controller action snippet here ...

```
  public class RoomController : Controller
    {
        ...
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(Room room)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the two syntaxes using the same action (same url in your case myurl)?

Comment: bro first syntax is perfectly fine, problem is that i have to pass a second parameter to the action so I need the second one

Comment: the only difference with my actions is that returns a JsonResult

Comment: In that case can you include the action definition as well as the definition for the complex object you are trying to pass to the action?